# No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add"

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, hook, phonegap

Hi I am using phonegap and cordova and trying to install phonegap-facebook-plugin with command

```
cordova -d plugin add /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="MyAppId" --variable APP_NAME="example"
```

but getting error No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add"

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPVLQ.jpg)

Do i need to add the scripts under hooks folder manually or what should I do?Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hook management has been updated over years it can produce this error.

So check your cordova version. it must match the expected cordova version of this plugin.